# Hide topbar while using Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

How to hide top bar (which includes buttons like clock, battery meter, etc ) on ubuntu 13.04 while using Google Chrome. Same feature can be seen on Sublime Text 2 when we use full screen mode (F11) and only tabs and page is visible (basically hiding the top bar).

Answer (score 2):

In the same way as Sublime Text 2: Press F11 and go Fullscreen :-)

Comment: Pressing F11 results in hiding of tabs and omnibox. I just want top bar to remove making only my chrome (tabs, omnibox, and page) visible.

Comment: You're asking **Google Chrome to modify its fullscreen behavior** or Ubuntu to have **Panel auto-hide feature**, which are new feature requests that should be made elsewhere, I'm afraid ;-)